# Recommended puzzles?

Tags: playfair, classical-cryptography

I am beginning my journey into Cryptography, having studied a theory-heavy master's degree module, and I have also read The Code Book by Simon Singh, among many other online resources.

What puzzle books would the community recommend, just so I can get into the mindset of code-breaking? I noticed that certain newspapers have puzzles that are just like the Playfair Cipher. This is something that should tilt a little more toward the fun side.

It might be against the rules to ask for specific books, if that is the case feel free to instead answer this question by recommending various types of puzzles.

Comment: You might like [cryptohack](https://cryptohack.org). I let the community decide if the Q in on-topic, should be a [meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114/555)… [off-topic: that's one of the hardest part of being a mod].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about cryptography per se. It's a reference request for crypto puzzles.

Answer (score 2):

For classical hand manual cryptography, the book [Cryptanalysis: A Study of Ciphers and Their Solution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PYZ3WUQ) by Helen Fouche Gaines is unsurpassed in my opinion. The exercises are entertaining and of a range of difficulties.

Another book is [Elementary Cryptanalysis a Mathematical Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000HZUN2S) by Abraham Sinkov. It's a bit more formal in tis approach, but still has enjoyable exercises.